# Release Health Details and Release Health Overview widgets are missing

Tags: azure-devops

**Context**

I am trying to add "Release Health Details" and "Release Health Overview" widgets to my Azure DevOps Dashboard, however those are missing from the "Add Widget" list, and also when I click on "Don't see a widget? Explore the Extension Gallery" link, I can not find them on the Gallery.

I do know how to add a widget to the dashboard (I can add "Deployment Status" and "Release Pipeline Overview" widgets)

**Question**

Am I missing something, or those widgets are gone?

Comment: Do you have the extension that provides those widgets installed in your organization? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.TeamProjectHealth

Comment: Many thx. Now I have :-). In case you post it as answer, I am going to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those widgets are part of the Microsoft DevLabs *Team Project Health* extension package. You need to install it from the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.TeamProjectHealth) in order to use those widgets.